# How to get followers list at the same time check weather am I following the followers?

Tags: mysql

I've been trying to get followers user info at the same time i would like to know weather am i following my followers or not ?

Where Am I

This query will get all the followers info but not weather i am following them back or not

```
SELECT
  follow.my_user_uid,
  users.username,
  users.full_name,
  users.rep,
  users.pro_pic
from
  follow,
  users
WHERE follow.followed_user_uid = '7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c' && users.UID = follow.my_user_uid;
```

My Follow Schema and all UID's

```
id |              my_user_uid             |         followed_user_id
85  7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    401895a0-3f1b-11e8-9c9c-81192d2dd899
87  7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    35790d90-402a-11e8-94d5-d7c3b5277172
89  35790d90-402a-11e8-94d5-d7c3b5277172    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
96  7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    def2e970-40e5-11e8-bd4e-cb404ee7672f
97  def2e970-40e5-11e8-bd4e-cb404ee7672f    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
98  b4eb3820-1fc6-11e8-aead-23ee40fdc27f    def2e970-40e5-11e8-bd4e-cb404ee7672f
100 b4eb3820-1fc6-11e8-aead-23ee40fdc27f    401895a0-3f1b-11e8-9c9c-81192d2dd899
101 35790d90-402a-11e8-94d5-d7c3b5277172    b4eb3820-1fc6-11e8-aead-23ee40fdc27f
102 401895a0-3f1b-11e8-9c9c-81192d2dd899    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
```

UPDATE

My Current Output

```
id |    my_user_uid                     |      followed_user_id    | username

89  35790d90-402a-11e8-94d5-d7c3b5277172    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    Byz5WlxhM
97  def2e970-40e5-11e8-bd4e-cb404ee7672f    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    iambad
102 401895a0-3f1b-11e8-9c9c-81192d2dd899    7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c    B1jgo7Ajf
```

What I want is and additional column with a title isAmIfollowingTheFollower with 1 or 0 respected values

```
 id |    my_user_uid                     |      followed_user_id    | username |  isAmIfollowingTheFollower
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the additional check using `EXISTS` operator:

```
SELECT
  f1.id,
  f1.my_user_uid,
  f1.followed_user_uid,
  users.username,
  users.full_name,
  users.rep,
  users.pro_pic
FROM 
  follow AS f1
INNER JOIN 
  users
ON 
  users.UID = f1.my_user_uid
WHERE 
  f1.followed_user_uid = '7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c' 
  AND
  EXISTS
  (
     SELECT 1
     FROM follow f2
     WHERE f2.followed_user_uid = f1.my_user_uid 
           AND
           f2.my_user_uid = '7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c' 
  )
```

**Output:**

```
id | my_user_uid                          |  followed_user_uid
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
89 | 35790d90-402a-11e8-94d5-d7c3b5277172 | 7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
97 | def2e970-40e5-11e8-bd4e-cb404ee7672f | 7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
102| 401895a0-3f1b-11e8-9c9c-81192d2dd899 | 7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e042e/1)

**Edit:**

To output a flag field that indicates whether I am also following my follower or not, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
  f1.id, 
  f1.my_user_uid,
  f1.followed_user_uid,
  users.username,
  IF(f2.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS isAmIfollowingTheFollower
FROM 
  follow AS f1
INNER JOIN 
  users
ON 
  users.UID = f1.my_user_uid
LEFT JOIN
  follow AS f2
ON 
  f2.followed_user_uid = f1.my_user_uid AND f2.my_user_uid = '7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c' 
WHERE 
  f1.followed_user_uid = '7fdb1960-517c-11e8-b6fd-3da507d1ce5c'
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e042e/3)

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am newbie,Your query is producing the same result as my past query there are no difference even though  row 85 and 102 following each other back it is not showing any difference

Comment: @Nane Row `102` is correctly included in the output result set of the query. Same thing with `89` and `97`. Check the edit I made. Do you disagree with the output? If, yes, then where and why do you disagreee?

Comment: No I am not disagreeing your answer,But what I am saying is that is not what i want I've updated the question with my desired output and Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: @Nane This additional column will be equal to 1 for *all* records returned using the sample data provided in the OP. Is that right?

Comment: Yes I am such a dumb yes I provided a sample data where that UID following back each other you are correct and I will use this query with other data or other UID